# In Linux how to run a shell script automatically when the headphone is plugged in?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, lubuntu

Is some kind of signal emitted when an earphone/headphone is plugged in? I want detect when they are plugged in and run a script accordingly.

Comment: You used confusing tags. Which are you running? debian, ubuntu, or lubuntu?

Comment: @Seth It should work with any Linux version I guess.

Comment: It depends on what Linux distribution you're using, and what type of hardware you are running it on.

Comment: Hi, yes it should work on all distros.
I tried the solution given in the question of which this is a duplicate. i.e. if fired the command

cat /proc/asound/card0/codec#0

However, the command shows no difference between the outputs when the headphone is connected to the jack and when it's not. I even did a "diff" between the two outputs to be sure.

What could be the problem?

(commenting here as I don't have reputation enough to comment there)